# Is there any pattern?

Tags: number-theory

I am printing ($m^2$ +$n^2$) in its increasing order , while $m$ and $n$ both run from $1$ to infinity. 
I want to know whether there is a pattern in ($m$,$n$) in this sequence.
I have printed some of its program generated output below.($m$>=$n$)

$1^2$+$1^2$=$2$

$2^2$+$1^2$=$5$

$2^2$+$2^2$=$8$

$3^2$+$1^2$=$10$

$3^2$+$2^2$=$13$

$4^2$+$1^2$=$17$

...
...

My questions are :

1. Is there any pattern in ($m$,$n$) for the increasing order of ($m^2$+$n^2$) ?
   I mean
   ($1$,$1$),
   ($2$,$1$),
   ($2$,$2$),
   ($3$,$1$),
   ($3$,$2$),
   ($4$,$1$)
   ...
   Are the pairs following any special pattern?
2. Is there any convenient way to write the outputs?
3. What happens if I take another variable p , running from $1$ to infinity , and watch ($m$,$n$,$p$) in the increasing order of ($m ^2$ + $n^2$ + $p^2$) ?

Comment: For two squares: if all of the primes that are one less than multiples of four have even exponents in the prime factorization of your number, then it can be written as the sum of two squares.

Comment: Strictly speaking: this is not a sequence. How do you order these numbers (there are two independent indices)?

Comment: @Crostul it is a sequence ... the first term is the lowest possible value of $m^2+n^2$, the second term is the second lowest, etc. - no need to nitpick :P edit: sorry, I think you have a point if OP is talking about the sequence returning $m$ and $n$ or something

Comment: See [A000404](http://oeis.org/A000404)

Comment: @Bonnaduck , in the above link , the sequence is just printed . It is not my motto . I am interested in the pattern of (m,n) in that sequence.

Comment: @PriyadarshiPaul did you miss $3^2+3^2$?

Comment: @Bonnaduck No, I just did not print it here , it is 18 , just after ($4$,$1$).

My friend has printed this sequence in C++ for $m$ and $n$ both running from $1$ to 20

Comment: I doubt there is a much better way to describe this sequence other than the way you have, then. If you do not arrange it based on increasing outputs, [A070216](http://oeis.org/A070216) may be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The locus of $m^2+n^2=s$, is a circle of radius $\sqrt s$. As you are producing the couples $(m,n)$ by increasing $s$, the pattern is that generated by a circle that grows on a square grid and crosses grid nodes.

As far as I know, there is no simple way to describe that pattern. The successive values of $s$ aren't regular, nor are the angles that subtend the corresponding points $(m,n)$.

See the related [Gauss circle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem).

The 3D generalization is with a growing sphere that meets the nodes of a cubic grid. Even less regularity.

Comment: Fully agree with the answer by Yves Daoust. Also interesting is https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~latte/background/countingLecture/poly/poly/index.php

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares), [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_three-square_theorem) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem) can gain you some insight. This three linked theorems show you, in a certain way, and under certain assumptions, what you can generate with sum of two, three and four squares.